# Binomial Regression where n > 1

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics, data

I am not well versed in Generalized Linear Models, but am trying to use this approach to model some discrete data. I have binomial data where the sample size for each observation is the same size, greater than 1, i.e. n  = 50.  I've been reading through the GeneralizedLinearModelFit and ProbitModelFit.  From what I can tell, these functions assume that you only have one trial per observation.  I'm wondering if I could define a custom LinkFunction to properly analyze this data.  If so, how would I do this?

Many thanks for taking the time to read this.

Mike

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I messed up in my original post and incorrectly used n^(1/2) as the weight.  I've fixed that and provided a more complete example.

If `n` is a list containing the sample sizes (all elements equaling 50 in your case) for a binomial variable, then you can account for potentially varying sample sizes by including the `Weights` option in the following manner:

```
Weights -> n
```

This could be made much more explicit in the documentation.  A more complete example might be

```
(* Data *)
(* Number of trials *)
n = {10, 20, 45, 50, 5, 18, 27};
(* Number of successes *)
y = {3, 6, 18, 31, 2, 12, 25};
(* Predictor variable *)
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

(* Construct input for GeneralizedLinearModelFit *)
data = Table[{x[[i]], y[[i]]/n[[i]]}, {i, Length[x]}];

(* Perform analysis *)
lr = GeneralizedLinearModelFit[data, z, z, 
   ExponentialFamily -> "Binomial", LinkFunction -> "LogitLink", Weights -> n];

(* Show parameter estimates *)
lr["ParameterTable"]
```

with output

```
    Estimate   Standard Error   z-Statistic   P-Value
1   -1.78374   0.442041         -4.03523      0.0000545491
                                                        -6
z   0.509998   0.108194         4.71372       2.43236 10
```

As a check here is the code and output using R:

```
n <- c(10, 20, 45, 50, 5, 18, 27)
y <- c(3, 6, 18, 31, 2, 12, 25)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
glm(cbind(y,n-y) ~ x, family="binomial")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     -1.784        0.510
```